Hazard Ratio from two cox models
I am working on a dataset from a clinical trial where patients received either treatment $A$ or treatment $B$. My goal is to develop two separate Cox proportional hazards (PH) models: one for patients receiving treatment $A$ and another for those receiving treatment $B$. After developing these models, I want to predict the treatment effect for a set of individuals (the same data source and another population) under both treatments $A$ and $B$.
Using the entire dataset, obtaining the hazard ratio (HR) is straightforward, as $ \exp(\beta_{\text{treatment}})$ represents the HR. However, I am now focusing on the more appropriate way to get a correct HR for separate models.
From the Cox model, we know that:
$h_A(t) = h_{0A}(t) \exp(\beta_A \times X_i)$
$h_B(t) = h_{0B}(t) \exp(\beta_B \times Y_i)$
When comparing the hazards:
$\frac{h_A(t)}{h_B(t)} = \frac{h_{0A}(t) \exp(\beta_A \times X_i)}{h_{0B}(t) \exp(\beta_B \times Y_i)}$
In the general case, the baseline hazard $h_0(t)$ cancels out, leaving us with the ratio explained by the linear predictors. However, in my situation, the baseline hazards are different for treatment $A$ and treatment $B$.
I am considering using the cumulative hazard function to address this issue. By calculating the survival function as:
$S_A(t) = \exp(-h_{0A}(t) \exp(\beta_A \times X_i))$
$S_B(t) = \exp(-h_{0B}(t) \exp(\beta_B \times Y_i))$
I can then compute the cumulative hazard function $H(t) = -\ln(S(t))$ for each group:
My question is: Can the ratio of the cumulative hazard functions $\frac{H_A(t)}{H_B(t)}$ be interpreted as the hazard ratio in this context? If not, what would be the most appropriate method to estimate the hazard ratio when the baseline hazards are different for the two models?
I run the two model in R, one using all individuals who got treatment A, and another for those receiving treatment B.
ModelA <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ age + gender + factorA + factorB, data = dat[dat$trt==A),]

ModelB <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ age + gender + factorA + factorB, data = dat[dat$trt==B,])

Then, when getting the base hazard for each of them basehaz(Model, center = FALSE), the get a data.frame with time and hazard. The time (slightly) differs between the ModelA and ModelB, but the hazard much more.
Last Observation (t)



Model
time
Hazard




A
89.2
2.5e-07


B
89.1
0.15




Welcome to Cross Validated! How do you know that "the baseline hazards are different for treatment  and treatment "? Is there an untreated control group involved? If not, how do you estimate the different baseline hazards? Please explain (and if possible, show what you found on that matter) by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Thanks for updating. It's not clear, however, what is different between ModelA and ModelB, as the formulas and data seem to be the same for both. Please check and correct or explain what I'm missing. In your data set dat, did any individuals receive both treatment A and treatment B? Did any receive no treatment at all?

Thank you for your help. I corrected the info, the formulas are the same but the data differs. The dat was divided into those who received treatment A and who received treatment B. All individuals received a treatment. The final goal is to be able to predict treatment effect (hazard ratios) for an individual based on their covariates. Each model will be applied to each individual and then the hazard ratio needs to be calculated, similar as meta-learnes do.

It's seldom wise to subset data and run separate models. I think that your separate modelA and modelB might be misleading you.
As each of those models is restricted to individuals who received the corresponding treatment, and no individual evidently received both treatments, each of those is essentially a model of how age and gender are associated with outcome within the corresponding subset of patients. It's not surprising that the baseline hazards for those highly restricted models might be different, if age or sex affect outcomes differently under treatments A and B.
Also, it's very hard to interpret a single estimated baseline hazard value without further information. Given that one of the hazard values you show is close to 0, these seem to be instantaneous hazards (from epiR::epi.insthaz() or similar software) rather than the cumulative hazards returned by basehaz(). If there were any events at all in the data for ModelA, the cumulative hazard should be above 0 after that event. If the last observations are right-censoring times instead of event times in the data for modelA, then the instantaneous hazards at those times would be 0 for that model. In any event, survival data can be notoriously unreliable at late times.
To test my guess that the different baseline hazards in modelA and modelB are because the effects of treatments A and B differ as a function of age or sex, model the entire data set while including interaction terms between treatment and age and between treatment and sex. You also should consider modeling the continuous age values flexibly (e.g., with splines) instead of imposing a strict linear association between age and log-hazard, as your current models do. I suspect that will give a model for which the proportional hazards (PH) assumption holds well enough, getting around your apparent baseline-hazard problem.
If PH still doesn't hold for treatment (the best way to test whether the baseline hazard differ with treatment), then there is no single HR between the treatments. Breaking the data into treatment subsets is not a good way to approach that problem. Even then, using the cumulative hazard at some particular time as an estimate of HR when PH doesn't hold, as you suggest, would depend heavily on your choice of time value. (After all, at infinite time the cumulative hazards approach infinity for both treatments.) The time dependence vignette shows better ways to deal with violation of PH.
In particular, a plot of scaled Schoenfeld residuals against time would show how the instantaneous hazard ratio (HR) between treatments changes with time. If the variation with time isn't too great, you can treat the estimated HR as a sort of average value; see this page and its links. Otherwise, you might be able to interpret the time course of HR changes based on your understanding of the subject matter.
